# App rejection for User registration

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I recently submitted a multiplayer trivia app to the app store. There are 2 versions of the app but they are essentially the same thing just for different trivia.

One app was accepted but the other rejected

Here is the rejected reason

17.2 Details

We noticed that your app requires users to register to access non account-based features. Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app content and features that are not associated specifically to the user.

My app has followed the process that is similar to other major apps like trivia crack and words with friends.

The user gets a screen to sign in with facebook or sign in with email.  When they click on sign in with email it brings them to a screen where they enter their email.  We then create an account for them in the app.

This is required so that we can keep track of the user in each of the games they are playing and who they are playing against we also keep stats for that user based on how many questions they get wrong and how many right, also how many wins.  We are storing all of this on our webserver so that the user can also use his account on a different device so that they can play their games on their iphone, ipad, ipod and so on.

We ask for nothing other than email, and if we dont have them register then we cant maintain all this information for them, especially if moving from device to device.  Again, this is how almost ALL other larger multiplayer apps in the store do it.  I mimicked them exactly.

I dont get it.  Plus, one reviewer accepted one of the apps and another rejected the other app.

Should I appeal?

Comment: I have run into a similar situation recently.  My suggestion is write an appeal and tell them what you just wrote here.  Worst case scenario you can just find another way to track user's besides their email address, like the Game Center account.  But definitely write an appeal before changing your app.

Comment: Yeah, gamecenter won't work because this is cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can appeal.
You can explain your position to reviewer, we had similar problem and after we've created appellation application was published.

Comment: Can you tell me how long the appeal took? I just would hate to appeal, they take a week only to say no and then I am back at the same point. Also should I appeal or just plead my case to the reviewer in the resolution center?

Comment: timur please can u tell me in detail what to write in appeal description